# How to keep track of the serverconfiguration: keep entire "/etc" in git

Tags: security, git, rootkit, etc

I want to keep my whole `/etc` folder in a `git` repository to track unauthorised changes by intruders and find out mistakes I could have done myself.

What would be the right way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://aymanh.com/version-control-linux-configuration-files-etc-etckeeper

Have a look at the above ... I was looking along the same....

Hope that helps

Comment: Some more useful suggestions and ofcourse etckeeper is mentioned too http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29117/how-to-keep-track-of-changes-in-etc

Comment: thx, that was what I needed

Answer (score 4):

Look into [etckeeper](http://joeyh.name/code/etckeeper/), there have been packages of it for Debian/Ubuntu for some time now, and likely packages are available for other distributions as well.